# android - no asimila nueva paleta de colores, sale error en el log

Tags: java, android, xml, botón

Al hacer un cambio en los colores principales de la aplicación: **colorPrimary**, **colorPrimaryDark** y **colorPrimaryLight**, todos los componentes asimilan el nuevo cambio, excepto los botones. Sólo me sucede cuando lo ejecuto en un emulador con la *versión 5.0 (API 21)*.

Así se ve en la API 21:

[image: Interfaz en la API 21]

Y debería verse así, como en la API 29:

[image: Interfaz en la API 29]

La estructura de los botones es:

```
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/register_cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="cancel"
                android:text="@android:string/cancel"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                style="@style/UnelevatedButton" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/register_accept"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:onClick="attemptRegister"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                style="@style/UnelevatedButton" />
```

El estilo que indico es el siguiente

```
<style name="UnelevatedButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.UnelevatedButton">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
</style>
```

Y la pila de errores cuando lo compilo en la API 21, por cada botón, es:

```
07-31 20:28:30.163 2941-2941/com.kcht.naughtclock E/AppCompatResources: Failed to inflate ColorStateList, leaving it to the framework
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 0
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.inflate(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:144)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXmlInner(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:119)
        at androidx.core.content.res.ColorStateListInflaterCompat.createFromXml(ColorStateListInflaterCompat.java:98)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.inflateColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:120)
        at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:78)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.TintTypedArray.getColorStateList(TintTypedArray.java:171)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatBackgroundHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatBackgroundHelper.java:61)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:75)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:68)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:192)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:111)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.kcht.naughtclock.gui.activity.RegisterActivity.onCreate(RegisterActivity.java:108)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Comment: Busca en el LogCat donde indique "Caused by" , lo que agregas actualmente no puede indicar el problema.

Comment: No tiene un "caused by", sólo aparece esa pila